# ubuntu 15.10 to windows8 from usb

Tags: usb, windows

ive been looking for the answer for my question for some hours and still couldn't find the answer even from the previous threads.

I'm using SONY vaio.

I'm trying to install windows 8 from a bootable USB stick that has win8 put on it, but even with the secure boot feature disabled it says "Operating system not found" is this a problem with the usb, windows that's been put on it, or do I have to do something in ubuntu before changing my whole operating system to windows?
Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Hypotheses:
1) Boot order thing on BIOS.
2) You didn't produce a proper bootable image of win8.
3) You can also try unpowering your device, taking of the battery and holding power for about 3-5 minutes. Then trying again. Another option is on BIOS turning off Virtual Processing(KVM), and then turning on again, if wanted.

Comment: I would say its mostly Hypotheses 2 .